# How to get parent from child in nested model rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have issue when try to get parent model from child as below:

Post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
        has_many :post_votes, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_votes
end
```

PostVote model

```
class PostVote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post, optional: true 
end
```

Get parent funtion

```
def find_owner_post_vote_for_user(user)
        @owner_post = Post.first
        @owner_post_vote = PostVote.first
        if user.id.present?
            @owner_post_vote = PostVote.where(user_id: user.id)
            @owner_post = @owner_post_vote.post
        end
        return @owner_post
    end
```

Error log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `post' for #<PostVote::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fffc23f9c78>):
```

Get child model @post.post_votes is OK, but get parent model is false.
Any can help me fix this problem? Thank so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostVote.where(user_id: user.id)` will return a collection of records. So, on the very next line when you do `@owner_post_vote.post` It's trying to find a `post` for a collection of records `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

if you want to use `where`, then you should iterate through the collection. Or, you can you `find` to get a single record. Then you can do `@owner_post_vote.post`.

Option 1:

```
if user.id.present?
   @owner_post_vote = PostVote.find(user_id: user.id)
   @owner_post = @owner_post_vote.post
end
```

Option 2:

```
if user.id.present?
   @owner_post_vote = PostVote.where(user_id: user.id).first
   @owner_post = @owner_post_vote.post
end
```

Option 3:

```
if user.id.present?
   @owner_post_votes = PostVote.where(user_id: user.id)
   @owner_post_votes.each do |post_vote|
      # post_vote.post is accessible here
   end 
end
```